# How do I change the label and help text of the publishing status checkbox?

Tags: 8

We recently updated our site to Drupal 8.4 and the widget for publishing a node has changed from a dropdown to a checkbox. Now, how do I change the label and help text of the checkbox? It cannot be changed in the field UI.

[image: publishing status checkbox]

Answer (score 5):

You can use hook_form_alter() to change label and help text
Use devel module to debug the label and help text change accordingly.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */

  function hook_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) { 
  if($form_id == 'node_page_form'){
   kint($form);
   kint($form['status']['widget']['value']['#title']);
   $form['status']['widget']['value']['#title'] = t('Published status label changed');
  }
}
```

After applying above code for basic page node form i was able to see the change in label of published text to Published status label changed

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try use the hook_form_alter,

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  //obtain the default value
  $value_status_default= $form['status']['widget']['value']['#default_value'];      

  //we modified the title of the field
  $form['status']['widget']['value']['#title']='Publishing Status';
  //we modified the description of the field
  $form['status']['widget']['value']['#description']='New Description Publishing status'; 
  //we modified the type of the field 
  $form['status']['widget']['value']['#type']='select';
  //we modified the options of the field 
  $form['status']['widget']['value']['#options'] = [
    true => t('Published'),
    false =>t('Not Published'),
  ];
  //we modified the default valueof the field       
  $form['status']['widget']['value']['#default_value'][]=$value_status_default;

}
```

the result
[image]

Comment: Nice.  I think `$form['status']['widget']['value']['#type']='radios';` (a pair of radio buttons) is quite a good choice for this for inexperienced users.  Note if you do that, a default value of false needs to be changed to zero for the 'Not Published' radio button to be checked.